# How to remove all 'nil' values from an array?

Tags: arrays, lua, null, lua-table

I have an array of objects (or just numbers), and I have another array which contains all the objects that should not be removed from the first array in any circumstances. It looks something like this:

```
-- Array of objects (just numbers for now)
Objects = {}

-- Array of objects that should always stay in the 'Objects' array
DontDestroyThese = {}

-- Populate the arrays
Objects[#Objects+1] = 1
Objects[#Objects+1] = 2
Objects[#Objects+1] = 3
Objects[#Objects+1] = 4
Objects[#Objects+1] = 5

DontDestroyThese[#DontDestroyThese+1] = 2
DontDestroyThese[#DontDestroyThese+1] = 5
```

Now, I have a method called `destroy()` that should remove all objects from the `Objects` array except those included in the `DontDestroyThese` array. The method looks something like this:

```
function destroy()
    for I = 1, #Objects do
        if(DontDestroyThese[Objects[I]] ~= nil) then
            print("Skipping " .. Objects[I])
        else
            Objects[I] = nil
        end
    end
end
```

However, as the result, the `Objects` array now contains `nil` values here and there. I'd like to remove these `nil`s so that the `Objects` array would consist only of the numbers that were left there after calling `destroy()`. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `table.remove(Objects, I)`?

Comment: `Objects[#Objects] = 1` doesn't do what you think it does because arrays in Lua start at index 1. Try `Objects[#Objects+1] = 1`.

Comment: I agree with @lhf's comment. The same goes for `DontDestroyThese[#DontDestroyThese]` - you must add a `+1`

Comment: That missing `+1` is a mistake I made while typing the code sample.

Comment: @manabreak you use wrong terminology. Objects doesn't contains nils "here and here". It contains holes, because in Lua assignment the nil to table[key] means "delete the key".

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler I did get my message through, though, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way is probably to create a new table to hold the result. Trying to move values around in the array is likely to have a higher overhead than simply appending to a new table:

```
function destroy()
    local tbl = {}
    for I = 1, #Objects do
        if(DontDestroyThese[Objects[I]] ~= nil) then
            table.insert(tbl, Objects[I])
        end
    end
    Objects = tbl
end
```

This method also means you don't have to deal with altering the contents of the table/array you're iterating over.

Comment: Thanks for this, somehow these overly simple solutions always go right over my head. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think the solution is much simpler.  To remove any nils ('holes' in your array), all you need to do is iterate your table using pairs().  This will skip over any nils returning only the non-nil values that you add to a new local table that is returned in the end of the 'cleanup' function.  Arrays (tables with indices from 1..n) will remain with the same order.  For example:

```
function CleanNils(t)
  local ans = {}
  for _,v in pairs(t) do
    ans[ #ans+1 ] = v
  end
  return ans
end
```

Then you simply need to do this:

```
Objects = CleanNils(Objects)
```

To test it:

```
function show(t)
  for _,v in ipairs(t) do
    print(v)
  end
  print(('='):rep(20))
end

t = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}
t[4] = nil          --create a 'hole' at 'd'
show(t)             --> a b c
t = CleanNils(t)    --remove the 'hole'
show(t)             --> a b c e f
```

Comment: But `pairs` iterates in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 0):

```
local function remove(t, pred)
  for i = #t, 1, -1 do
    if pred(t[i], i) then
      table.remove(t, i)
    end
  end
  return t
end

local function even(v)
  return math.mod(v, 2) == 0
end

-- remove only even numbers
local t = remove({1, 2, 3, 4}, even)

-- remove values you want
local function keep(t)
  return function(v)
    return not t[v]
  end
end

remove(Objects, keep(DontDestroyThese))
```

Comment: Note that `remove` runs in Θ(n), and so this code has quadratic complexity.